# CORS error when accessing static resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

Despite having the following config, accessing http://localhost:8080/rooms/rooms.json gives me a CORS error - *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*.

I have no problem to request any other path which is mapped by controller. What is the problem with static resources? How to allow cors request or exclude the resource paths without spring security?

Spring Boot 2.0.5

Spring Boot Web Starter 2.0.5

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/rooms/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/rooms/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Answer (score 2):

Update `addCorsMappings` like below it could work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/rooms/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/rooms/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
        .allowedMethods("POST", "GET")
        //.allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
        //.exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
        .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with the following configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourcesCorsConfig
{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Note, that Spring Boot will only send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header back on a GET request, if the Origin-header is present on the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@CrossOrigin(value = "*")` to your controller class. You can replace * with any particular URL in case to allow that origin only.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost")
    @GetMapping("/rooms/")
    public Object rooms() {
       // your implementation
    }
```

You can do in this way.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.viator.com/orion/nova/public/mmblite/styles-53929dcb.css

Experienced the same problem actually, but found the root cause and a solution.
Your request was most probably cached by intermediary: load balancer, CDN or caching HTTP server in front of your application as regular non-CORS request. Then you have sent request with `Origin:`, but the intermediary returned you the same cached response because from point of view of the cache responses by default are identified by `/path` + `METHOD` + `Host:`-header which were the same. To tell caches that the request with `Origin:` and the regular request (without `Origin:` need to be cached as independent entries in any cache we need `Vary: Origin` header in both responses. This was fixed/implemented in Spring 5.2.x (in my case it was Spring 5.1.9), in your case it was 5.0.9 (as dependency of Spring Boot 2.0.5.). Once I upgraded to Spring 5.2.0 all was fixed once caches on the intermediary had expired. I recommend to upgrade beyond 5.2.6 (cause there were further changes in CORS handling, which are nice to have).

here is the line (which made the difference) they (Pivotal) commited into Spring: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d27b5d0ab6e8b91a77e272ad57ae83c7d81d810b#r36264428

and their bug description: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22273